# Error Nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException WebFlow

Tags: hibernate, spring, jsf, spring-webflow, jboss7.x

I have a error like this working with webflow 2.3.0.RELEASE and richfaces 4.0.0.Final in jboss 7.0.1.FINAL:

> 12:16:46,989 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 2011-09-20 12:16:46,987 [MSC service thread 1-7] ERROR (FrameworkServlet.java:314) ï¿½ Context initialization failed 12:16:46,989 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowExecutor': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.webflow.config.FlowExecutionListenerLoaderFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'flowExecutionListenerLoader'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1':Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaFlowExecutionListener' while setting bean property 'listeners'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaFlowExecutionListener' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/transportes-webflow.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined.

Well I suppose that the error is because I have the Hibernate configuracion in META-INF like this:

> - META-INF/spring/spring-master.xml
>
>   - META-INF/spring/spring-hibernate.xml
>   - META-INF/spring/spring-datasource.xml
>   - META-INF/spring/jdbc.properties

and the webflow configuration in WEB-INF:
WEB-INF/spring/transportes-webflow.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces-2.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!--Flow executor for Jpa integration and security  -->
<webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
    <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
        <webflow:listener ref="securityFlowExecutionListener"/>
        <webflow:listener ref="jpaFlowExecutionListener"/>
    </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
</webflow:flow-executor>

<!-- Flow register -->
<webflow:flow-registry flow-builder-services="facesFlowBuilderServices"
                       id="flowRegistry" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows/">  
    <!-- <webflow:flow-location path="/welcome/welcome.xml"/> -->
    <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/*-flow.xml"/>
</webflow:flow-registry>

<faces:flow-builder-services id="facesFlowBuilderServices"
                             enable-managed-beans="true" development="true"/>

<!-- For use interface flow controller -->
<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
    <!--  need to tell Spring Web Flow about how to handle Ajax requests. -->
    <property name="ajaxHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.faces.richfaces.RichFacesAjaxHandler" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry"/>
     <property name="defaultHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<!--  LISTENER'S for SECURITY and JPA-->
<bean id="securityFlowExecutionListener"
      class="org.springframework.webflow.security.SecurityFlowExecutionListener"/>

<bean id="jpaFlowExecutionListener"
      class="org.springframework.webflow.persistence.HibernateFlowExecutionListener">
    <constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="transactionManager"/>
</bean>

<!-- Facelets config -->
<bean id="faceletsViewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.faces.mvc.JsfView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/flows/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml"/>
</bean>
```

This is my full prompt for downloaded:

https://rapidshare.com/files/335929555/prompt-jboss.zip

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
```

means that it is unable to locate a bean definition for `entityManagerFactory`. From your webflow config it is needed by `jpaFlowExecutionListener`:

```
<bean id="jpaFlowExecutionListener"
  class="org.springframework.webflow.persistence.HibernateFlowExecutionListener">
    <constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="transactionManager"/>
</bean>
```

In case this bean is defined in:

```
META-INF/spring/spring-hibernate.xml
```

It should either be imported by a webflow config (`WEB-INF/spring/transportes-webflow.xml`)

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/spring-hibernate.xml" />
```

Or make sure you have these two files in your Web config listener:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:META-INF/spring/spring-hibernate.xml /WEB-INF/spring/transportes-webflow.xml ... </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```